# Save a Shell sort process in C # in WPF

Tags: wpf, sorting, shellsort

I have been studying the Shell sort.

I would like to output the process of shell sort.

The Swap and save information when you have been Swap.

And if the output array will appear rightly.

However, the position of the seat is changed, the number is displayed incorrectly.

How should I save? change position(sortInfo.Position),

change target position(sortInfo.TargetPosition)..

I would like to know the value put on two variables.

If you need a different code Leave a comment

```
    #region ShellSort 
    public int[] ShellSort(int[] data, int[] intervals)
    {
        int i, j, k, m;
        int N = data.Length;

        // The intervals for the shell sort must be sorted, ascending
        for (k = intervals.Length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            int interval = intervals[k];
            for (m = 0; m < interval; m++)
            {
                for (j = m + interval; j < N; j += interval)
                {
                    for (i = j; i >= interval && data[i] < data[i - interval]; i -= interval)
                    {
                        Swap_arr(data, i, i - interval);

                        sortInfo.Position = i;  // change position
                        sortInfo.TargetPosition = i - interval;   // change target position
                        sortInfo.SortingNumbers = data;    
                        sortingInfos.Add(sortInfo); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: I _think_ the problem is in the usage of the `sortInfo` object - there seems to be only one that is reused all the time. It probably needs a new instance every time and the `data` array needs to be cloned before being put in. But it's really hard to understand what you are asking...

Comment: possible duplicate of [I try to save a heap sort process in C # in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703476/i-try-to-save-a-heap-sort-process-in-c-in-wpf)